# Does public static functions of base class become member functions of derived class if base class is inherited publicly?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors, singleton

I am trying to run the following code but getting error.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public :
    static T& Get() {
      static T t;
      return t;
    }
};    
class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
  private :
    Derived() {}
    // friend Base<Derived>;  //un-commenting this will make code work.
};                            

int main() {
  Derived& d = Derived::Get();
  return 0;
}
```

> Error :
>
> > prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static T& Base::Get() [with T = Derived]’:
> >     prog.cpp:18:24:   required from here
> >     prog.cpp:7:14: error: ‘Derived::Derived()’ is private within this context
> >     static T t;
> >             ^
> >     prog.cpp:14:4: note: declared private here
> >     Derived() {}
> >     ^~~~~~~

I have following questions

1. class `Derived` is publically derived from class `Base`, doesn't it makes `Get()` a member function of Derived too ?
2. If [1] is true, and `Get()` becomes a member function of `Derived`, then
   why it's not able to call the private constructor of `Derived`.
3. Assume we have multiple classes to be implemented as Singleton, is
   there a way we can do it using templates with something similar to
   the above example? (additional question)

I understand :

- We can make the above code work by making base a friend of derived
  line to the code.
- We can make `Get()` as "non static virtual function" and override in
  the derived classes.

I am not looking for the above mentioned solutions. Though, please let me know if this(these) is(are) the only possible solutions to achieve this kind of design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> class Derived is publically derived from class Base, doesn't it makes Get() a member function of Derived too ?

Yes in the sense that the lookup `Derived::Get()` will work, but it call the very same function as if you wrote `Base<Derived>::Get()`.

> If [1] is true, and Get() becomes a member function of Derived, then why it's not able to call the private constructor of Derived.

Because different classes cannot access private members by name. This is what private is for. The same reason why `Derived` cannot access private members of `Base`.

> Assume we have multiple classes to be implemented as Singleton, is there a way we can do it using templates with something similar to the above example? (additional question)

Isn't that what your example is doing?

> We can make the above code work by making base a friend of derived line to the code.

Correct.

> We can make Get() as "non static virtual function" and override in the derived classes.

I don't think so. You cannot call that virtual function without an object. You'd be required to create an instance of `Derived` before calling `Get`, but `Get` is supposed to create our object.

> Though, please let me know if this(these) is(are) the only possible solutions to achieve this kind of design.

I would probably go forthe friending. Simple, concise and does what you want. There is other solutions like having a protected type in the base, and defining a public constructor that receive that protected type, but this is quite leaky and I won't recommend.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. class Derived is publically derived from class Base, doesn't it makes Get() a member function of Derived too ?

No. Member functions (static and non-static) of base are member functions of base, not member functions of the derived class. However, the member functions of base(s) are looked up when invoking a member function (depending on visibility).